# Array of Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

How do you create an array of arrays in C#? I have read about creating jagged arrays but I'm not sure if thats the best way of going about it. I was wanting to achieve something like this:

```
string[] myArray = {string[] myArray2, string[] myArray3}
```

Then I can access it like `myArray.myArray2[0];`

I know that code won't work but just as an example to explain what I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple example of array of arrays or multidimensional array is as follows:

```
int[] a1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] a2 = { 4, 5, 6 };
int[] a3 = { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
int[] a4 = { 50, 58, 90, 91 };

int[][] arr = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
```

To test the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" +  arr[i][j].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wish to initialise a multidimensional array: int[][] myArrayOfIntArrays = { new int[] { 0, 1, 2 }, new int[] { 3, 4, 5 } };

Answer (score 7):

you need a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), that is the best solution here

```
int[][] j = new int[][]
```

or:

```
string[][] jaggedArray = new string[3][];

jaggedArray[0] = new string[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new string[4];
jaggedArray[2] = new string[2]
```

then:

```
jaggedArray[0][3] = "An Apple"
jaggedArray[2][1] = "A Banana"
```

etc...

**note:**

> Before you can use jaggedArray, its
>   elements must be initialized.

in your case you could wrap the array in another class but that seems highly redundant imho

Answer (score 4):

You can use List of List. List - it is just dynamic array:

```
        var list = new List<List<int>>();
        list.Add(new List<int>());
        list[0].Add(1);
        Console.WriteLine(list[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is through jagged arrays:

```
string[][] myArray;
```

Your way doesnt really make sense:

```
myArray.myArray2[20] // what element is the first array pointing to?
```

It should be at least (if possible)

```
myArray[1].myArray2[20];
```

This is clearly worse than the standard way you would do things with jagged arrays: `myArray[1][20];`

Comment: What to do if you don't know the array limit? like a DB query?

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran you won't be dealing with  arrays to begin with so I don't really understand  your question.

Comment: Ok, am working with Cassandra, and i got an object of data. i got a list data type, need to know how to use it.

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran You seem to have a question, well then, *ask* a question; comments are not the tool you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand your real aim. But as option you can use `dynamic` type to create dynamic dictionary as decribed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx#Y2299) (see **examples** section).
But its more likely that you need multidimentional array as described in others answers

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing to get a list of strings that an enum represented.  Here is a possible solution:

```
     public enum Group
     {
          All = 0,
          Artists = 1,
          Builders = 2
      }

      private static readonly string[] _rolesAll = { "Brett", "Jeff", "Virgil", "Danielle" };
      private static readonly string[] _rolesArtists = { "Brett", "Danielle" };
      private static readonly string[] _rolesBuilders = { "Jeff" };

      private static readonly SortedList<Group, string[]> _sortedGroupToRoles = new SortedList<Group, string[]> { { Group.All, _rolesAll }, { Group.Artists, _rolesArtists}, { Group.Builders, _rolesBuilders } };
```

then to use it:

```
      _sortedGroupsToRoles.TryGetValue(Group.Artists, out string[] roles);
```